# Optimal use of indexes for aggregate queries

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing

My `Postgres` table looks something like this:

```
tran_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
acct_id int NOT NULL,
tran_type char(2) NOT NULL,
/* some performance irrelevant fields */
```

The only multi-row query the application will run is as follows:

```
SELECT acct_id, COUNT(tran_id) FROM table WHERE tran_type = 'X' GROUP BY acct_id;
```

So I always just want to pull a list of accounts that have a particular transaction type and get the number of transactions of that type.  With that in mind, what are my best choices for indexing:

1. index on `acct_id` and index on `tran_type`
2. composite index on `acct_id` and `tran_type`
3. 1. and 2. combined (3 indexes total)
4. something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2. But the **sequence of columns** is essential. Make it:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_mult_idx ON tbl (tran_type, acct_id)
```

Also, it would be more effective to have an `integer` column (or an [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html)) instead of `char(2)` for the type.

And use `count(*)` instead of `count(tran_id)` if `tran_id` is defined `NOT NULL`. It's a bit faster.

More details in [this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Answer (score 0):

build your number 2 :). It is just one index - will be easier to maintain, it will serve your query perfectly, and even more - it will not use table at all, just index!

under number 4 could be materialized view